# conserving hierachy in LASSO, stepwise approach using penalty.factor?

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, elastic-net

I'm using the lassop {MMS} in R to run elastic net on fixed effects in a mixed model. My model includes several higher-order interactions, and I'm interested in keeping the main effects in the model to conserve hierarchy.

The lassop function includes the penalty.factor argument from glmnet. My question, is it valid to disable penalties on main effects (set penalty factor to 0) to maintain hierarchy of interaction terms?